# How do you disable the unused variable warnings when you are not sure that what you have is variable

Tags: c++, macros

There are many different techniques to disable unused variable warnings. Some with void, same with attribute. They all though assume that you know that it is a variable.

I have a case of macro that changes its behavior from release and debug, say:

```
#if NDEBUG
#define MACRO(X)
#else
#define MACRO(X) do_something(X)
#endif
```

Code like:

```
void foo(int a) {
    MACRO(a);
}
```

may result in warning in release. I would like to change this to:

```
#if NDEBUG
#define MACRO(X) UNUSED(X)
#else
#define MACRO(X) do_something(X)
#endif
```

So the question is what I should define `UNUSED` to, when the task is complicated from the fact that the argument to `MACRO` is not limited to variable, but it could also be a function call or any other expression. Or

```
MACRO(5);
MACRO(a+b);
MACRO(foo());
```

are also valid uses of `MACRO`

Comment: You should identify the variable that is only being used for debug statements, and conditionally compile out the variable (not just the debug statements using the variable).

Comment: there are things that work, but I am concerned that in not all cases the compiler will be smart enough to filter out the code.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend allowing code that can have potential side effects to be used in debug only.

Comment: @jxh this is what I do now, I say `UNUSED` when I know it is variable before I do `MACRO`, but this is what I am looking how to improve eliminating the need of this

Comment: How does one assume that calling functions in debug version has the same functionality as the release version?

Comment: not all functions and even more expressions have side effects

Comment: @CrazyEddie yes, it is kind of error prone, but we all do this all the time, don't we? ... and this is why we should use clang-tidy

Comment: I did it at one job because it was convention there, but otherwise no...not really.  I felt dirty doing it even then.

Comment: so you do not use `assert` in your code - wow great

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I like:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define MACRO(X) ((void)sizeof((X), 0))
#else
#define MACRO(X) do_something((X))
#endif
```

The names you use in the macro argument end up being used, but in an unevaluated context and then that gets cast to `void` which prevents a different warning.

Comment: I will try this one, and let you know

Comment: @jxh see my edit. We'll just add a comma expression.

Comment: gcc 4.8 - it does not work with void, and reports: error: left-hand operand of comma has no effect for constant

Answer (score 1):

You might have:

```
#define UNUSED(X) (false && ((X),true))
```

<sup>*and-then* with *comma-operator* (for typing reasons)</sup>

Or

```
#define UNUSED(X) do{if (false) (void)(X);}while(0)
```

<sup>always false conditional</sup>

Comment: The second one still does not compile with void (but that is ok),compiles in most of my other cases and seems to be dropping the expression without evaluation, but this is one compiler. I will give it a try for a while before confirm.